# boostrap not working in angularjs routing

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

angularjs routing , I created an index file (index.jsp), there is a link which directed to another jsp file that created using HTML and bootstrap, but when the page is loaded to main website, bootstrap styles are not working in the main webpage.

```
<body >
   <div class="body container" ng-app="myApp">
    <header>
    <div class="head container" style="background-color: greenyellow;">
        <h1>Cargo Management System</h1>
    </div> 

</header>

<div class="bodycontent container" style="background-color: blueviolet;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;">

            <div class="sidebar container"  style="background-color: brown;width: 25%;margin-left: 0px;height: 500px;float: left;">
                <h3>side bar</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#/!" >Menu1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#!four" >Warehousing</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="background-color: cyan;width: 100%;padding-right: 0px;">
                <h1>content</h1>

                <div ng-view class="container" style="background-color: black;width: 100%;padding-right: 0px;">
                   <script>
                            var app   = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
                              app.config(function($routeProvider) {
                              $routeProvider
                              .when("/four",{
                                  templateUrl : "Warhousing.jsp"
                               });
                            });
                   </script>
                 </div>
            </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
      <div class="footer container" style="background-color: yellow;">
   <h1>Footer</h1></div>
  </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

other jsp file

```
   <body>
     <div class="body1 container" style="background-color: yellow;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 5px;">
       <header>
            <div class="head1 container" style="background-color: green;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;">

                <button class="headbtn btn btn-default" >Insert Cargo</button>
                <button class="headbtn btn btn-default" >Search</button>
                <button class="headbtn btn btn-default" >Release Cargo</button>

            </div>
        </header>
            <div class="warehousecontent1 container" style="background-color:red;">

                 <h1>Container</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does this mean is your bootstrap expects the DOM content to be present before. But in your case may be you are adding the DOM contents dynamically at run time. I'm not sure which library you are using.

Comment: i'm using online bootstrap

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>